# IntentHandler doesn't update

Tags: swift, swiftui, sirikit, widgetkit, custom-widgets

I have configurable widget with dynamic options. The user can select different options like "Widget1" or "Widget2" ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWng5.jpg)).
The data are provided by UserDefault and can be modified in the main app.

When I change tеxt for "Widget1" in the main app and do an update to widget (`WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()`), the widget doesn't update its view and also selected option ("Widget1") is not selected anymore, until I select it again (and it will show the data I need).

Is it possible to update IntentHandler?

Any ideas are welcome! Thank you

IntentHadler file:

```
    class IntentHandler: INExtension, ChooseWidgetIntentHandling {
    
    func provideStylingOptionsCollection(for intent: ChooseWidgetIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Styling>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let stylingConfiguration: [Styling] = Widget.array.map { widget in
            let styling = Styling(identifier: widget.name, display: widget.name)
            styling.text = widget.text
            styling.category = widget.category as? NSNumber
            
            return styling
        }
        
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: stylingConfiguration)
        
        completion(collection, nil)
    }
```

1. Selected option - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw2Ix.jpg)
2. After I changed data (text) and updated widget nothing changed - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi5Wh.jpg)
3. Selected option ("Widget1") is not selected anymore - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NccnP.jpg)
4. When I select option it shows the data, that I need - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdljz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: after a few desperate weeks, I didn't find a solution, but I made it work. I'm changing the options of configuration in `func getTimeline`. To avoid making changes to all configurations (widgets in my case) I check the current configuration with a unique identifier (just one of my options, it can be a name of configuration or something like that) and change it only for one configuration.